# Cant set the theme to dark in Iced Rust

Tags: rust

im trying to learn Rust and the 2Iced" crate and im currently trying to set my app to Darkmode but i dont undestand the documentation and dont know what to do.

```
use iced::{Application, Settings, executor, Theme};

struct MyApp;


impl Application for MyApp {
    type Message = ();
    type Flags = ();
    type Executor = executor::Default;
    type Theme = **Theme::Dark**; //error[E0573]: expected type, found variant "Theme::Dark"
```

```
fn main() {
    let settings = Settings::default();
    MyApp::run(settings).unwrap();
}
```

i dont know how to implement it in another way.

I tried random stuff like:
iced::Theme::Dark
iced::theme::Theme::Dark
Dark

Comment: That's not a type, that's a specific variant. If you want that theme as default, you'll need to `impl Default` for it. Maybe this is something you should specify in the `Settings` implementation? What this code says is "Please specify what your theme *type* is" not "what your *theme* is".

Comment: I think you can override the `theme` method to return a `Theme::Dark` instead of the default `Theme::Light`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, it's expecting a type, so you must do `type Theme = Theme` and to set the dark theme you need to implement the `theme` trait item:

```rust
impl Application for MyApp {

    ... 
    ...

    type Theme = Theme;
    fn theme(&self) -> Self::Theme {
        Theme::Dark
    }
}
```

For examples on how to use the `iced` crate check the [github repo](https://github.com/iced-rs/iced/tree/master/examples)